# User able to login without giving the credentials in Angular 8

Tags: authentication, angular8, angular-services, angular-forms, angular-httpclient

I am building upon an app that uses Angular 8 for the front end and Spring Boot for the back end. I am currently working on the login and the registration component. I have created the backend api's using Spring Boot and using MySQL database. I have registered two users using the POST method in Spring Boot and they're available in the database. Now I use them in my login and try to login, but my login seems to accept empty values and random values. Where do I go wrong? I've checked all the api's in postman. Since I am new to angular, I am not able to debug it. Any help or reference would be appreciated.

admin-login.component.html:

```
<mat-card class="admin-login">
    <mat-card-header class="login-header">
        <mat-card-title>Admin Login</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content class="content"> 
        <form class="admin-login-form" (ngSubmit)="loginUser()">
            <small class="alert">{{ message }}</small>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="admin-user-name">
                            <input matInput placeholder="Email ID" [(ngModel)]="user.emailId" name="emailId" type="email" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="admin-password">
                            <input matInput placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" type="password"
                                name="password" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </mat-card-content> 
    <mat-card-actions class="action">
        <button mat-raised-button type="submit" (click)="loginUser()" color="primary">Login</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
    <a class="register" mat-menu-item routerLink="/adminRegistration">Register</a>
</mat-card>
```

admin-login.component.ts:

```
import { LoginService } from './../../login.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from 'src/app/user';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-login',
  templateUrl: './admin-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-login.component.css']
})
export class AdminLoginComponent implements OnInit {

  user = new User();
  message= '';

  constructor(private router: Router, private service: LoginService) { }

  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  loginUser() {
    this.service.loginUserFromRemote(this.user).subscribe(
      data => { console.log("Success"),
                this.router.navigate(['/admin'])
              },
      
    error => { console.log("Failure"),
              this.message = "Invalid credentials";
            }
    )

  }


}
```

login.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  user: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public loginUserFromRemote(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/admin/login", user)

  }

  public registerUserFromRemote(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/admin/register", user)

  }
}
```

Comment: what your api returns ?

Comment: I was a backend error and I just fixed it. Thank you